# How to handle IO streams in Spring MVC

Tags: spring-mvc, inputstream

I have a method which returns **ResponseEntity(InputStreamResource)**. In this method, I'm getting InputStream from a file based on the filename input and then sending InputStreamResource as a response.

**Code snippet**

```
InputStream inputStream = ...;    
ResponseEntity<InputStreamResource> response = new ResponseEntity<InputStreamResource>(new InputStreamResource(inputStream), headers, HttpStatus.OK);
return response;
```

Here do I need to close inputStream object? If I do so, I'm getting

> IllegalStateException: Closed message.

Do I need to explicitly close them or container will take care.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The underlying class where this is handled is [ResourceHttpMessageConverter](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/http/converter/ResourceHttpMessageConverter.html) and it closes the underlying input stream as is evident from [here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/master/spring-web/src/main/java/org/springframework/http/converter/ResourceHttpMessageConverter.java#L139)