# Unreleased InputStream in InputStreamResource returned from REST controller

Tags: java, spring-mvc, file-io, fortify

I have such a method in my REST controller, returning file data:

```
@RequestMapping(
        value  = "by-id/{attachmentId}",
        method = RequestMethod.GET
)
public ResponseEntity<InputStreamResource> attachmentById(
        @PathVariable("attachmentId") String attachmentId) {
    GridFSDBFile file = service.getAttachment(attachmentId);

...... some unrelated code here, setting headers, etc .....

    return new ResponseEntity<InputStreamResource>(
                new InputStreamResource(file.getInputStream()), respHeaders, HttpStatus.OK);

}
```

This works fine, but by the report of Fortify, I shall release InputStream, obviously opened in `file.getInputStream()`. Probably, I had to use either try-with-resources, as InputStream is autocloseable, or to call `file.getInputStream().close()` in `finally` block. But it seems that I cannot do so, because I exactly do not know the implementation of neither the constructor of `InputStreamResource` nor its methods, whether that input stream may be still in use in returned ResponseEntity.

What am I to do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that you have been able to find an answer to your question. And, probably, it is a question to Fortify, because stream is closed by Spring - see "investigation" - [How to handle IO streams in Spring MVC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48660011/how-to-handle-io-streams-in-spring-mvc)