# Error http/1.1 405 Can not download file using spring boot interaction AngularJs

Tags: java, angularjs, spring-boot, jasper-reports

I used spring boot api. I created a api to export PDF file and use a jasper report. In the font-end section I used Angularjs. When I click the ExportPDF button and then I get the Error error message http / 1.1 405 Unable to download the file. I do not know that this error of font-end or back-end. It took me a long time for this. Please help me:

This is my code back-end : Controller

```
@RequestMapping(path = "/reports_statistic_orders", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ResponseEntity<byte[]> reportsStatisticOrders(HttpServletRequest request) {

        Map<String, Object> parameters = new HashMap<>();
        String username = "Louis";
        parameters.put("username", username);
        byte[] bytes = jasperReportService.createPDF("report_order", parameters);
    return ResponseEntity
            .ok()
            .header("Content-Type", "application/pdf; charset=UTF-8")
            .header("Content-Disposition", "inline; filename=\"" + username + ".pdf\"")
            .body(bytes);


}
```

This is my Repository :

```
@Autowired
   ReportRepository reportRepository;

   public byte[] createPDF(String inputFileName, Map<String, Object> params) {
    return reportRepository.generatePDFReport(inputFileName, params);
   }
```

Code implement :

```
private final StorageService storageService;

@Override
public byte[] generatePDFReport(String inputFileName, Map<String, Object> params) {
    return generatePDFReport(inputFileName, params, new JREmptyDataSource());
}

@Override
public byte[] generatePDFReport(String inputFileName, Map<String, Object> params, JRDataSource dataSource) {
    byte[] bytes = null;
    JasperReport jasperReport = null;
    try {
        // Check if a compiled report exists
        if (storageService.jasperFileExists(inputFileName)) {

            jasperReport = (JasperReport) JRLoader
                    .loadObject(storageService.loadJasperFile(inputFileName));
        } 
        // Compile report from source and save
        else {
            String jrxml = storageService.loadJrxmlFile(inputFileName);
            jasperReport = JasperCompileManager.compileReport(jrxml);

        }
        JasperPrint jasperPrint = JasperFillManager.fillReport(jasperReport, params,
                dataSource);
        bytes = JasperExportManager.exportReportToPdf(jasperPrint);
    } catch (JRException e) {
        throw new ApplicationException(APIStatus.ERR_LOAD_FILE, e);
    }
    return bytes;
}
```

FileSystemStorageService file :

```
 @Component
```

public class FileSystemStorageService implements StorageService {

```
private final String folder = "/report";

@Override
public boolean jrxmlFileExists(String file) {

    String tmpPath = folder + "/" + file + ".jrxml";
    URL url = getClass().getClassLoader().getResource(tmpPath);
    File reportfile;
    try {
        reportfile = new File(url.toURI().getPath());

        System.out.println("PATH reportfile jasperFileExists: " + reportfile.getAbsolutePath());
        System.out.println("PATH reportfile.getAbsolutePath() : " + reportfile.getAbsolutePath());
        return true;
    } catch (URISyntaxException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(FileSystemStorageService.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);

    }
    return false;
}

@Override
public boolean jasperFileExists(String file) {

    String tmpPath = folder + "/" + file + ".jasper";
    URL url = getClass().getClassLoader().getResource(tmpPath);
    File reportfile;
    if (url == null) {
        return false;
    } else {
        try {
            reportfile = new File(url.toURI().getPath());
            System.out.println("PATH jasperFileExists reportfile: " + reportfile);
            System.out.println("PATH jasperFileExists reportfile.getAbsolutePath() : " + reportfile.getAbsolutePath());

        } catch (URISyntaxException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(FileSystemStorageService.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        return true;
    }

}

@Override
public String loadJrxmlFile(String file) {
    String path = "";
    String tmpPath = folder + "/" + file + ".jrxml";
    URL url = getClass().getClassLoader().getResource(tmpPath);
    try {
        path = URLDecoder.decode(url.getPath(), "UTF-8");
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        throw new ApplicationException(APIStatus.ERR_STORAGE_FILE_NOT_FOUND, e);
    }
    return path;

}

@Override
public File loadJasperFile(String file) {

    String tmpPath = folder + "/" + file + ".jasper";
    URL url = getClass().getClassLoader().getResource(tmpPath);
    File reportfile;
    try {
        reportfile = new File(url.toURI().getPath());
    } catch (URISyntaxException e) {
        throw new ApplicationException(APIStatus.ERR_STORAGE_FILE_NOT_FOUND, e);
    }

    return reportfile;
}
```

}

This is my code font end

```
$scope.exportPDFOrders = function (){

                Util.createRequest('/statistics/reports_statistic_orders', function (response) {
                    var status = response.status;
                    if (status === 200) {

                    } 
                });
            };
```

And show message 3 error :

[Error http/1.1 405](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7CMKQ.png)

[Error had been blocked by CORS policy](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e0vfa.png)

[Request method 'POST' not support](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JkUs9.png)

Comment: Did you try to debug?

Comment: yes, I takes very long time for that. I think it is font end error

Comment: Have you tried building and returning a Resource instead of a byte array? See this https://stackoverflow.com/a/35683261/1624052

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. I tried returning a resource but still got an error. Now, I added jquery at the end of the font, and it worked. But the file I downloaded is corrupted in format