# How to write a Rest API in spring boot to download an excel sheet that is present in the resource?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I want to re-write a legacy code in spring boot. When the api is hit, the excel file in the resource should be downloaded. The following is the part of MVC code using JSP Servlet.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/downloadTemplate", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public void doDownload(HttpSession session,
        HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException {
    String fn = "/resources/files/censusTemplates";

    try {
        InputStream inputStream = servletContext.getResourceAsStream(fn);

        response.setContentType("application/xlsx");
        response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=SimpleStandardTemplate.xlsm");
        FileCopyUtils.copy(inputStream, response.getOutputStream());

        inputStream.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        logger.debug("An error occurred while trying to downloadTemplate: {}", e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

Please help me to implement in Spring boot.

Comment: Please follow the below URL https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35680932/download-a-file-from-spring-boot-rest-service

Comment: Does not match my requirement.

Comment: What of the Spring MVC code does not work in Spring Boot? My expectations ist that the so-called legacy code will be running in Spring boot out of the box.

Comment: What *exactly* do you expect the new code to do that the old code doesn't?