# Convert/write PDF string/byteArray to a pdf file

Tags: java

I am getting PDF octet/Stream string from the response when i write it to the file it opens blank

```
<200 OK,%PDF-1.7
%
7 0 obj
<<
/Type/XObject/Subtype/Image/BitsPerComponent 8/Width 2480/Height 194/ColorSpace /DeviceCMYK
/Filter/DCTDecode
/Length 46976>>
stream
[S6CÞSÙào Æ]VB%ìÀ­gh®q5XE`êÜ<Úæ ®Ëêél¨¤\Á¶N ó¸Z8òVpü.Æ@e®ÿ®¨VåØ¡Î>>^m1»Dñ5íx1Pti¬ Ù[ÓÚz¼ëæÏRþW¸"rú:)j¾MUµm>WI®MªØ`)Y \÷&NÍ­fM¡O¼!zªÄlËà
s¨vnüà/ÐHg'ù}ÒXcÔñK¶ÙàÙ$û³O9VÞ{k]= 5CYàpÛOÍeä!;ÚA)`Õ.W´
¯ðÏôþå;d%»¥WbêÍmG3âãÞm#|´õy7Ë}TÍ$iÖen'1:|®Jöd(ðÝ(Áë*(Ü>ãnH±ÕáËûzG¹Ø8 ³aû©ö¿Õ ÁÝXT¶vB«\t¦Ciz÷R{*Î8&ªöÊ "xühìXÚc49zGÓ   /~«HÁvØHp½»ððq-/øÇEiÕÒ-
    åÐ8#Ð+O~ËX[ÃÍh¢OÀ]¦¶Ê&äÃW¿Ñ@ÿkÀyÄ
cîßÀ5Å;wf!ÿb;7­cü¢©jÏÙ#^ÓXO0IfÑ?¹k¦«R8+¯¯Î¢«(Jgè=3<d)Á¬Ã¬»ÙSRFo}dâ"1a¦{úµ\°;èLàãÛ<APRÿÕ*5öìàÞï³\Í½D×Ú>hxGë,b¸½Km¥¥ºÙÏ\ÍgØìr(~¡
 ¢v"«^¤?;¼Hqj«ô7Ìlå9r@btZ6aô£=ö{@¡¡ç©+ `hCX¥þìé9ã´ð4¤9íÇp®òj>ß80¦Kµ¡m»°¦«µÛ½êª2bxZÝÃÜ\3mos©?N>oÍLÃÙ4Î#±
µ¨U·sÅ
uÝ´ÄÿDi6zWBóåxíIÂµèI
g>ñtQùaoÊ-ðÄË-¹)x
íäüTÌ<bH¢e³0ÁkÎY_ægÅdävdªPÎCJv,£F8Qá3Ú$#_L
¿ª/þá ë¡ü A0Ö&vî_0÷ÙíBºªî÷²óC0_7´±ðúéºÚìæ@.«´]æ/g5d¡kº99   ?|Õß,Ó°ôDÒkÔßÒî¥wb´Ð«Ô³¦×ô¦×Å¶îýZT{MT¼'ÍúËJ¬¡:£Ö±çNã[YÊbR¥òÔ]\a`|6/`¯ÌÄHâOVWÕïSÒzCW¼ß¯9/
â?éw¸Uì$oL±IÅD×Â&åðÃÑEHÊ&`
Ö;Ks}ùm÷õ¨î`7h¶'£Íi`lÿèã>a·@*;<5HKxåiëg8ä1g.$ÄËÔYMø¯AE7Ä½
´{ÓT!;Q·êÕªe@ígß=Ëa*R°1£ ä´yI)'TGX$wÞW
¬4 *
}*ÝzDÚ÷q>Ønõ0öõ¡ì2ié¦Oñä `"ÖËxiÃaf´}Eëµèqý¨3§U6âØ¢t©#cSÕ,
±[ªÿþ¯ßì]¢ðÒÜ®$©oAÌÌoWì×È
¸:ÕÝ5pLwø(®j §^0i[UÁ¸6¼÷ïRå2[ý6b´ *NT74Î¬Úp¹ÓM3éµ¾¨Ñ&N¥U²ïÂskÔz##±¤rRÈãn .Äc)MÛæ³H@7
¬´ÍF*ÊdÖÅ(¹ ÿ¤Â%üÞuëh öA¹9÷/Î?z58õ3Æk5²I1&fCôbí`¹qÃ²¸Nx3 ¬+*Vp.1k¦Tþòõ4R`ó6rè¯&íM]&+Sº\ÿ^Â²¾t8.ÊX^Jbõ)æáåÆÄVUò;òý üµ86Ù¢·ÁyÂ?>øÊ÷Ñ$@ëÇÖK¥>«~-åwzûþ¤È)´û§*<ðB,"£¸j¾ü\Edi^±g] ÿ¸~q%r^¨£¥á_QFK;Q°oÑ|0*¿°»wÐAÎÛÙù¸À|."Ð@>­Üp"uá> fÅt]ÙEÁÇ¶ãÛLPQZ
ðFBÏâ¤F²¾Î"PÀïH «¸>x9Ò±"&)£1º_ò%ðOd!H)-ö{¬²«éf¤nõ×ÕLbÚÞûHE
```

```
ResponseEntity<String> response = restTemplate.exchange(downloadFileUrl,HttpMethod.GET,request,String.class,urlParams);
        System.out.println(response);
        try (OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("C:\\Users\\downloaded.pdf")) {
            out.write(response.getBody().getBytes());
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Please if you can help how i can create a pdf file from the above byteArray

Comment: Do I understand it correctly that you are "reading" the response as String before writing it to the file? Maybe that's the problem, your `ResponseEntity<String>`. maybe [This Post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35680932/896249) can help you

Comment: Why do you think that a PDF document is a string? It is not, and converting it to a string will breaking it.

Comment: Hi Thanks , changed the response to  `ResponseEntity<ByteArrayResource>` and write `out.write(response.getBody().getByteArray());`  .problem solved