# Read Image file from disk dynamically in SpringBoot

Tags: java, spring-boot

I'm getting an OutOfMemoryError exception while reading image file from disk folder. 
What I do:

```
@GetMapping(value = "/user/image")
    public ResponseEntity<byte[]> identificationImage(@RequestParam String path, @RequestParam String filename) {
        byte[] image = Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get(path, filename));

        return ResponseEntity.ok().contentType(MediaType.IMAGE_JPEG).body(image);
    }
```

Is there a way to read files without loading into memory or something?

Out of memory error in a spring boot + spring data web application.

Comment: What's the size of the image you want to load and what does `Paths.get(path, filename)` evaluate to? Are you sure it is the image and not the directory?

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35680932/download-a-file-from-spring-boot-rest-service) might help.

Comment: What do you need to do with the image? Would splitting up the image & processing it chunk by chunk (by streaming the image data) be possible, or do you need to display the full image?

Comment: @hotzst 10MB. Path evaluates ok (/var/storage/images/user_image.jpg)

Comment: @VinceEmigh Yes I need to display in my backoffice. Would I have to increase my memory max size or is there a way to handle this without loading the image into the memory all at once? thanks

Comment: @hotzst image is 700KB sorry

Comment: Maybe you can split the image, so you only have to load a fraction at a time. You'd load one slice, draw it, load another slice, draw, etc... In the end, you'll need enough memory to handle the *drawing* of the full image either way, so increasing your memory is probably the easiest and safest option.