# How send file through http from one end point to another end point in spring boot application

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-rest, rest

I am building a spring boot rest API in which. I want to send the file via HTTP from one spring rest API application to another rest API  application and get a response whether the file successfully sends or not.

more explanation about the above scenario

I have 2 spring-rest-API. one running on port 4000 and another on 5000 on the local machine. I want to send a file from 4000 port rest API to 5000 port rest-API via post request and 5000 port rest-API will give a response whether the file successfully received or not. as this process is asynchronous. I also want to know how to handle it asynchronously.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

REST APIs are not designed to send files. You can send information about where a file is located(like a repository or cloud storage) so that the other end can take it from there, but not the file itself.

Comment: other than the rest is there any way to send file from one end point to another?

Comment: check out this one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35680932/download-a-file-from-spring-boot-rest-service

Answer (score 0):

My little suggestion is u can try to send the file content between the API or like @razvan said. Different port wouldn't be an obstacle to call each other.