# How to convert PNG data string to downloadable file in ReactJS?

Tags: javascript, java, reactjs, spring-boot, react-redux

I am trying to create enable user to download this
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fCxve.png) that is stored in my AWS S3.

My Java server sends back a **ResponseEntity<ByteArrayResource>** object, which is received by the frontend in the form of the below JSON response:

```
{
  "data": "�PNG\r\n\u001a\n\u0000\u0000\u0000\rIHDR\u0000\u0000\u0002\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0002\u0000\b\u0006\u0000\u0000\u0000�x��\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0019tEXtSoftware\u0000Adobe ImageReadyq�e<\u0000\u0000\u0018pIDATx����U\u001c��\u0000P�/�&�\"��\u0011L����\u0017��\u0011\f\u0013�0\u0011p\u001d\u0001&\u0002�\b`\"����\u00002��\u001a�ܱ���R�콖�׽_�B�st�R�\u0004\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000��^�\u0002��b�n\u001b�-{�v�O\nuy�\u000b�J��\u0002\u0000�\\��_��+N\u0000�������:V��-\u0000�ϡ�\u0004\u0000��4X\u0001��g\u0005�o;h0�?�\u0003^��-\u0000��[�\r\u0000�i��o\u001b\u0000\u0000������\u001c\u0006�J�\u0002�z��\u001b���\n\u0018ꑯ�]4�\u001b��{�Ԡ\u0002\u0000�;\f\u0010�S���\u0001@\u0002\u0000\u0014o�V`L�\u0000��U�m���\u000b��\u0002\u0000�\u001d��\u0000\u0010�Ej���/ۅ?;\u0000�u\u0001��/\u0004B\u0005l\u0001��\u000e�v\u0000��*p\u0005�ʟ\u001f������6\u0000L�\u0016\u0000L�\u0017]�\u000f\u0000���/��B �\u0000\u0000�8H�ߩ���n\u0000\t\u0000D���/`R�\u0002�iD��ߦ|!\u0010T\u0000 �(_�۔/\u0004�\u0004\u0000Bx�\u000b�\tL�\u0016\u0000��ڽ�\r��@P\u0001�f)u�\u001b�\u0000@@J��\u0006�`\u000b\u0000ƣ��c�\u0001@\u0005\u0000���\u0002}\u0004@<����\u000b�P\u0019[\u00000�.��~S���\r0,[\u00000�^\u0017�+P\u0001�xn���ljU�\u0000�\n\u0000̚/�=M�|!\u0010$\u0000Ѐ��@�Aml\u0001����n�l\u0003�\n\u0000�ء��,]r50H\u0000`�\\o��J�\u0000��W����]�g��rO7\ffQ�JW@,\u0007%8�v,H\r�On�۶��� ���_Ͽ7. `���D���i�_�K\u001f\u0005��G�hg��?��K\u0002 h���I\u0004v��\u0012�w�T�v\u0013���ǒ\u0000\u0010��J\u0004L\nO�l�u�\u0010�w�.J�JJ����>��%\u0001 �?:\u0001/u�7���N����\u0002������W\u0004�m�E\u0002*\t\u0000�_\"�\u001d��\"���~՞\u001f�>���m��\u0002�$\u0000\u0004��Wa}�/��{`0b2�\u000fP}�\u0004��\u001f>\u0011\u0010��\f\b��\u0000\u0010�\u0007N\u0004�\u001aZy-��Ki��&8M�l]-ʳv3b�I\u0002@��h�8�i\"0�ĪMs��h���x��Z\u0012\u0000�s���j_����R\u0015�2�K\u0002@��z��*�~ݮ\u0004���*�yV��01�\u0004��?�D��ՔV�Y�\u001a�V5\u0006~I\u0000\b��-�>L�\u0002�������e��V�$\u0000\u0004��/\u0015�}5�՟�\u000e�\b,�<���\u0004��_e\" �k�'\u0002s\r��\u0000\u0010���TH��jO\u0004��֫��\u0000\u0010�'M\u0004���\u0013\u0001J\u001b����\u001f\u0016l-�K\u0002@���\u0016�����\u001a�t��$\u0000\u0004��&�>��O��b\u001551�\u0004��\u000b]0����~��n�ޯ�����|���\\��yP�g���uyN�\u0000 �\u0003�\u0000$\u0000\b��$\u0000\t\u0000�? \t@\u0002��\u000fH\u0002�\u0000\b��\u0002�\u0004 \u0001\u0010�\u0001$\u0001H\u0000\u0004\u0000I\u0000\u0012\u0000�\u001f@\u0012�\u0004@�\u0007�\u0004 \u0001\u0010�\u0001$\u0001H\u0000\u0004\u0000I�\u0004\u0000�\u001f@\u0012 \u0001@�\u0007�\u0004H\u0000حnݮ\u0004�ϒ�W��\u0015�y�\u000b&\u0019�\u0000�\u001b%\u0000\u0001\u0007�{�\u0000���\u0012���\u0002�F.��$�\u0000\u00009��K\u0000T\u0000\"\r�s�\u0000��\\(��\u0000�ҕ*\u0000@dy���\r*\u0000��\u0001�A7\u0000�}\u0010�U\u0000T\u0001\u0000��Q\u0001P\u0005\u0000��G\u0005�m�V�+�\u0000\u0004�/�q��\n@h�\u0001��\r@ ���\u0004�{��\u0002���\u0004 f6�\n\u0000��\u0000Ȉ\u0001�u\f�!���W\u0002;�\u00004*����\r*\u0000Ȍ�X|\bM\u0005\u0000U\u0000 �U���\u0007\u0015\u0000T\u0001\u0000s\u001b*\u0000�\u0002\u0000V���tA�����\u0006�\u0011�&\u0017��\u0000��E�\u0002,t\u00050swe��+��\f@�\u000f�Ӳ@\u000b�\u000b�*\u0000�\u0002\u0000V��\u0000�\n\u0000X��\u0002���\u0000��\u0001��=\t�\n\u0000ϯ\u0002|�\r�\f}\u0010�U\u0000�N���\u0002\u0000�I��_�\u0006\u0015\u0000�o�\n\u0000�p�/��\u0000�\n\u0000X��\u0002�*\u0000`��\u0004����\u0002�\\�\u0004 ���\u0000�SH\u0000��9M�\u001c�\u0004@v\r`~B\u0002 �\u000607�!�\u0001�S~%��\r@%V���?T\u0000�i\u0003�$T\u0000P\u0005\u0000��Q\u0001@�\r��P\u0001@\u0015\u0000��G\u0005�'x�\u000b\u0000s\u0010*\u0000�,J\u0015`�+��ݕ����P\u0001`�\u0007P\u0006\u000eL��\u0017�U\u0000P\u0005\u0000��Q\u0001@\u0015\u0000��G\u0002��.u\u0001`��)l\u0001��bݖ��\u001dM��\u0012���׺A\u0002���u;�\r�]����\u001f���\u001d��\u001e���t�����.\u000f�ݺ}�\r\u0012\u0000��'��2���>�?˿�\u0013�w,K\"�S�WR\u0010�j�^%g\u0001`\u0012�����|�oy���a��m�E�o<-���v��cӰ\n\u0000�L�^�k{��n�e�5G]I\bު\u000e4��0�\u0013��&W�G��-���6���ډ�\u0018ƝLM<m��t_2��B>(���߿�֙�a\u001c�&�fV���p\u0016�\u0002�4o\"�տ����l�\r���o�\u0011U\u0000�꿹��4|h)\u0011P\u0005\u0000��[)�\u001f\u001a�Ov�l\r�\u0002\u0000V�3l��ۑ!���䰠*\u0000X��`f��kQ�g؝E�ګ*\u0000X�k\u0015�|-��P\u001d̲����\n\u0000�V@ʠ�D�ޱ�V���\n\u0018��B��]s;�\u0003�\u0000\t1D`�o���+c�\u0006�[\u0005\u0000�ԛL��ܼ�W�CIr��74a;ʜJ���-�:�\u0015���&���Ǥ�_�E�\u001b\u0019����aY����jouA5>���%�=��]�\u001b}�\u0015�0��j�\n�^&��\u001b��4U3\u0015\u0000�1�1�wV���ؼ�\r�2�#\u001fBqҟ�yC��\u000fb\u0001\u001bZ�4&\u000f�N���@\u0012�0 _�\u0005P'\u0007g��\u000f��^�k]ь��7u�Ӝ\u0006ճZ��)�����v3 Ԭ7Y8����\u0005����$�Ջ��o���3�S�ޝ\u0000�9\u0004X\u0017���;O�\u0017��]��c��\u0000P�7�`Tׂ�$��\u001e渰^�j�Ҙ����\u001fY�#�\")M�i/y%S\u0005��(�Y�1>U s�\u0004��)���?��/�u^�\u0004�Pl\u0001�#���!�Y�\u0015�/�g/o\u0005�\u0002zx����\r*\u0000�;\u0014�G�N��\u001bA�V�xɖm\u0000\t\u0000�Ϻ`\u0014�'��|�u\u0019#��B�\u0005P����N7\f>���\rl�*�\n\u0018�j��u�\n@t��?�_u\u0001Ɗy\u000f\t@M��`p����n`C��[\u0001�>\u0018���cw�\u000f�\u0019R\u0007,yγ���6\u00170\u0011R�|�o�vd��LG��Ѿ\u0012�\u001bn�,��rjU1j�1��ҍ�h�j�i� ��'�OL\"�5\u0013\t�H�=K�$�'��\u0018�L�nǂ~\u0015���\u000b��L�\f\u001c'o\rP�|�%�\u0017^yX�iKÒ\u001dYz��iWe�ux�Ƀ~�\u001c��G\u0015@���d��<\u001c��\u0000��zÔ\u001d�=WU7�\u0007\u0019�Ar����s�g>o\u00128<�V��\u0004�����\u000b0�7\t:C�q>\u0006�u��e��2�Yʟt�O>��0\u0016%��s���1��u;O�\u001f\"�\u001e�>9���> \f���6\u000e\t�\u0012���J�\t����\rC;�5�&A�ÃѶ\u0000�\u001f�M�W�ז\\��}qƐ�\u0001:�Д�m��\u0007>�i(cw���?�\u0015�\u0001]C�\u0002P���������\u001c�a����1�9�}rx�z��}=(��<�\u001ab\u0015���eN\n��u��n`D9\u0010�膰^�\u0011\u0012\u0000���غd\u001b@\u00020s/�\u001d�����q\u0007\u0012\u0000��\u0005\u0018{ \u0001 �O�\u0000c\u000f��\u0019\u0000�n/���i��෺A�T\u0001��]\u000b�L讌A�\u0000�\u0004\t\u0000\u0018� \u0001 �?u\u0001� H\u0000��\u0002c\u00106�\u0010 �/�{\b8��\u0000`�\u0005�\"\u0001I\u0000�+��1\u0016A\u0002@@�\u0002�E�\u0000`�\u0005�\"H\u0000\b��+�\"H\u0000\u0000���\u001a �.�\b8��\u0000\u0000@@\u0012\u0000\u0000�\u0000�,\\�\u0002*�  \u0012\u0000���\n�\u0004\u0000\u0000�\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0012\u0000\u0000@\u0002\u0000\u0000H\u0000\u0000\u0000\t\u0000\u0000 \u0001\u0000\u0000$\u0000\u0000���\u0018\u0010�.�\b8��\u0000\u0000@@\u0012\u0000\u0000�\u0000�l,u\u0001�\"H\u0000\u0000\u0000\t\u0000\u0001\u001c�\u0002�E�\u0000\u0010�B\u0017`,�\u0004�x~�\u0005\u0018� \u0001��\u000b�Ex\u0002\u0017\u0001a�����s�\n\u0000s��\u0005\u0018� \u0001 \u001e��1\u0006A\u0002@@?�\u0002�A�\u0000`�\u0005� l�!@�no��t\u0003\u0013ȧ�ou�ة\u0002\u0000�X�\u0002�=�\u0000\u0010�\u001b]��\u0007\u0012\u0000����\u0003\t\u0000\u0001t���\u000e�;$\u00000�C]��?�M\u0000�i�_��ڟ5���\u0000c��]�\u0018���\u000fj�.���\nI�tQ��J70��r�\u001bB�s��u;7��Sޫ;)\u000f�_Z���Pg$G����M�\u0019�_�\u0014�kj�*���\u0013��e����\u0011�$���ܕU���/\u0001����ݦ�kY\u0019���Yk�}L\u000e\u0011��+\u0001��]x\u0018f�N\rg\u0006v�9�}�(s~�*�\u000b��g��\r����m\u0019o?�6\u0000�-\u0016n\u0004�Y�'�ϒ�|<!\u0019px�a@x���<\u000f�u�.�8(��[\u000f�,\u001ez\u0018��@�����*�\f�0�\u0007����);�{��?��0\u001f�y8<�M�:\u000f��.9$\\�\t�>9�A\u0005�@�\u001f��PVӖ�%;��<UӮ�\\+�S�nݎ��BU\u0000���]��9N\u000e�13�!���\u0013d[��#���.&\u0012o\u0012x#�y����_�N����{\u0001�����=�\u0007��,�\u0017�_U80�s�Mպ���x6'�R\u0017L*_Y{�\u001b\u0006���\r<�o���Βk�\t��\u0012�Z UYz^Fi��6-\u001f\u0003���\u000f/\f�n`\u0003�]s�χ�J�\u001f�bB�\u0000�p�\u000b\u0006�'�c��\u000f\u001c\u000b��<\u0018�w��k&w��$zF��\u0011�-�z8�>��\u0015�:9|��\u001e�ȑ \u000e/?{{�az�\u0000�q�\u000bF[�y+�/�&���`*}R\u0016T�d\n��|�;$[\u0000�x�x�q�2d�\n��\u0015�+B.�\u0019�^�\u0005W\u0005[\u0000u\u0005$'c�M�NM�ƀ10�s�_\u0002��>��W��!��d��\u001c\u0007\u0015�H�\u0011��$\u00011���?~Sm���@\u0007�\u0018Vo�O��?*b\u000b@����\b%\u00011�����\r��3�^\u000fd���7�g�Q\u0001`\u0003�\u0006��\u0012�`X{\u001c�4��,,�\u0018&_�H\u0002�\n��j��\u0001�qcҘ<\t�\u001d0������0��-�z��\u0005�ʯ+�S˽�����\r�zf.��\u0005 �\u0007�\b���o�z�\u001ff�e%.\u000b�s㹁��&��.2����j�\"���Ұ��2�T���É��\u001cxV�|V�-�&\u0012o\b�]N�;;\u0003�2���N�-�)-���Xt�\u001f4�؄bK��(��ݎ\rQ��JG\u0015����x.��1�!�6ͣ\u001a�4T\u0007�����\u001fDԙX�\r\b\\\u0001��?��\u0019��\n\u0010�\fzd�n�(����\u0007T\u0001f��P�2�t��\u0007���\u0001U�\u0006�Er>`\u0013��Wƌ�?�\n�\\\"�\u001b�_�\u0005~�@\u0015 ��@�ߎ|XpQ�@���\u001fP\u0005\byX0O��.\u0013:(���>��\u0019�\u0016�nU��ɴ��o��Wf�.�u��&y߼U��v�n�붚q�ϧ��&�%��n��˿����>�T\u0006NK0�9�[���S+}W`�\u0002��\u0013�U��\u0016�:�۟��ˉ�;�ee�S��*?�\\�ze�/\u0001`:}r\u0002��D O������mr�,�\u001e�����`ϻu��\u001b$\u0000L�%3lb�d@pgӱ�Z7H\u0000�޲$\u0001\u0000cx���zbG^�f\u0012\u0000\u0000s\u000e*\u0000�x\u001d\u0010\u0018���T\u0000�@��d�i\u0016\u001e>w�\u0002��?�\n�\n\u0000c�\u0005`�\u0005H�\u001bT\u0000�F^�w�\u0001�ȪT\u0001P\u0001`�տ�\u000fL�S\u0005P\u0001��\u001fP\u0005@\u0005\u0000�@\u0015\u0000\u0015\u0000��\u0001U\u0000T\u0000��R�\u0007*�\u0002,u�\u0004�a��\u000b\u0000s\u0013\u0012�x�Y6`~B\u0002 �\u00060G!\u0001�]\u0003���\u00004�.\u0000�U��\u0000�K���\u0001�A~%p�\u001bT\u0000؞}5���\n��?�*\u0000*\u00002i\u0000s\u0017*\u0000M��۾�\r�L��۝nP\u0001��t\u0001`\u000eC\u0005 �����\u000b0Gy���\n�\u0002��3g�\u001f��BF\u0015@\u0005\u0000�@\u0015\u0000\u0015\u0000��\u0017���\u00164��A\u0005�����\u001b�F�J\u0015\u0000\u0015\u0000~��\u0017���tenC\u0005\u0000�@\u0015\u0000\u0015\u0000��\u0001U\u0000T\u0000��\u0001�t�n�t�\n\u0000�[\n�@�\u000e�\\�\u0004���\f�\\�\u0004 ��_V\f��\u0000Ȉ\u0001�y\f�!���=�+�\u0000\u0004�\u000f\u0003^�\u0006\u0015��~�\u0005��\u000f\u0015�X�t��\u001f@D�b��nP\u0001��>\u0018`\u000eD\u0005��\u001f@\u0015\u0000\u0015\u0000�/��\u0010\u0015��,���+���J\u0015�NW�\u0000Dp$�\u0003�� :�\r*\u0000V�\u0000�\u0000�\u00004�\u0000\u0000`n�\u0000\u0004�Z��2]�V���7\u0001Fg\u000b`:�\n�\u000bY/ ��\u0012X\u0002 \t\u0000\u0010��\u0000H\u0002\u0000\u0004$\u0000�\u0000\u0000�\u001f\t�$\u0000@�G\u0002 \t\u0000\u0010��\u0000H\u0002\u0000\u0004$\u0000�\u0000\u0000�\u001f\t�$\u0000@�\u0000 \t\u0000\u0010�%\u0000H\u0002\u0000\u0004\t\u0000�\u0000\u0000��9>\u00064\u000f��\u0007��o���å!Ae.����s*��P���u�+P˿�8}]����&X_h���2\u0016�mQ�l�g��4\r��]L�G���\u001eQ'Z������y\u0014$Q\u0015�A\u00120Ȋ�G�D{\"(i#�����8-W�\u0004�\u0004�\u001e��ԭ۩\u0000�\r�N�\u0018�Fk���\u000f��g��v�r��\"\u0011�j\u000b�_Z��/�\u0003ᒀ!\u0002�D@�=�\b\b� \tx֤�\u001c�\u001e\u0012\u0001�\u0005�M\u0002�\u0018���D�4\t�@�I�\u0014�ꗼ5�ms��dU�\u0007f�\u0004�\u0010�\u001fӯە�\u0017�]��\u000f�FI\u0004\u0004�\u0004�f5�Z�U��VԜ�V�?H\u0002�\t��M�Q.m�|k�ь���ϵ�\u000f���ÿh��\u001c\u001al�P_+\u0001l�ƽK@�\u0007I�`���.���\u0002���� cs�D@�\u0007I�l\u000eN���\f�\u001f��}6�O�?�*��$`��{�\f�&���\u001f5�?f�vs���\u000f�\u0000�C���\u00031\u000e\u0010�s���9�O\u0004\u0004�\u0004����i��\"��=�]\u001bݧ:�y�+��?H\u0002���gN\u0016\u0002�Κ���I�\u0012\u0001�\u001f\u0002'\u0001S݁�2\u0007\u0006ws���&\u0002��?H\u0002nӼ/�]/�o�z�h�����?�\u0017� ���4�q+�z�<.�tà�@n+]\u0011�K]\u0010�J�\u001fܹ.�w\u0015'X��\u0004\u0000\u0018�']��F�\u0000`x���N7<I^���\u0006P\u0001�9S��g\u0000\u0004�OY;����d:\f�\u0016\u0000��6��VI�\u001f\u0006g\u000b\u0000�q�\u000b�\u0015�\u0000@<]�\u0002�c���i�\u0002\u0000��\u0001�Z7�е�\u000f\u0012\u0000h�Ҷ>�j�\u0002���kWou�w��N\t*\u0000Д\u001cؼ��m�?H\u0000�U���7P\u0005[\u00000.�\u0000ߦ�\u000f*\u0000Ь\u001c�>膯|\u0010�A\u0002\u0000�S��'09[\u00000��\r��\r�+�=�\u0000*\u0000\u0010��\u0001�\u0005\u0000\u0001�B�/�\u0001\u0010ԍ���\b0\u0015[\u00000\u001d�o}\u0000@@�\n��}\u0000\u0000�\\\u0005\u000e�W��0\u001d[\u00000�3�\u001d\u0000���?\u0000�t\u00110�_��ôl\u0001����f`l�\u0002��E�B�/��\n\u0000��\u0003a����\u0005�\u0000\u0000���V`L�\u0000�\u001e\u0011�\u0010���\u0002\u0000|��o\u0004$\u0000\u0010�'�\u0011\u0000bj�\u000b���\u0007*\u0000�7��m\u0000\u0010�A�\u0015�\u0003^\u0000��\u0016�\u0001���2�\u0000�>��&\u0000��K��\u0007\u0000!]5\u0014���9�>�\u0000�Ng~\u000b0$W\u0001C�Z�B�/�\u0001\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u00003��\u0002\f\u0000Ĝ7Q��\u0016�\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000IEND�B`�",
  "status": 200,
  "statusText": "",
  "headers": {
    "cache-control": "no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate",
    "content-length": "6350",
    "content-type": "image/png",
    "expires": "0",
    "pragma": "no-cache"
  },
  "config": {
    "url": "/bond/download?id=1",
    "method": "get",
    "headers": {
      "Accept": "application/json, text/plain, */*",
      "x-id-token": "eyJra..."
    },
    "baseURL": "http://localhost:8080/",
    "transformRequest": [
      null
    ],
    "transformResponse": [
      null
    ],
    "timeout": 0,
    "xsrfCookieName": "XSRF-TOKEN",
    "xsrfHeaderName": "X-XSRF-TOKEN",
    "maxContentLength": -1,
    "maxBodyLength": -1
  },
  "request": {}
}
```

which I store inside a variable called **fileData**.

When I write this

```
var fileDownload = require('js-file-download');
fileDownload(fileData.data, `filename.png`);
```

and try to open the downloaded file, it says

```
Could not load image 'filename.png'. Fatal error reading PNG image file: Not a PNG file
```

My browsers (Firefox and Chrome) can display the image in the **Inspect Network**, and Postman can display the image too. It just doesn't work when I try to download it via javascript.

Was wondering if anyone knows how to download the PNG data string?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution here https://stackoverflow.com/a/60351773/13181010 .

Turns out I need to add

```
{ responseType: 'arraybuffer' }
```

in the axios request, like below

```
axios.get('http://localhost:8080/yourdownloadurl', { responseType: 'arraybuffer' }).then((response) => {
      var fileDownload = require('js-file-download');
      fileDownload(response.data, 'test.pdf');
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried a different approach from your Spring back-end?  I would suggest returning your PNG image as a byte array, and annotate the REST Controller method to indicate the appropriate [`MediaType`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/http/MediaType.html) that it produces:

```java
@GetMapping( value = "/get-png-image", produces = MediaType.IMAGE_PNG )
public @ResponseBody byte[] getPngImage() throws IOException {
    // your code to acquire PNG from S3 and return as byte[]
}
```

Edit:

According to the documentation for [`js-file-download`](https://github.com/kennethjiang/js-file-download), another thing you probably need to review in your front-end code is the data format you are passing to `fileDownload()`.

For binary data (such as images), `fileDownload()` requires that the `data` you pass in be a [`Blob`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Blob).

The `js-file-download` documentation provides the following example illustrating this:

```js
import Axios from axios;
import fileDownload from 'js-file-download';

function download(url: string, filename: string) {
  Axios.get(url, {
    responseType: 'blob',
  }).then(res => {
    fileDownload(res.data, filename);
  });
}
```

I would expect the combination of back-end and front-end changes to resolve your issue.

Comment: I tried your advice, it's the same outcome ---> Could not load image 'filename.png'. Fatal error reading PNG image file: Not a PNG file

Comment: @jyl_ljy_work I have edited my original answer to include front-end updates that should also be implemented.

Comment: @Phillip Wrage Thanks, I will try it out

Answer (score 0):

if your blob is base64 Format, you can add content_type to the first before return it.

```
fileDownload(fileData.headers.content-type, ',', fileData.data, `filename.png`);
```

so maybe the fileDownload need to add `data:image/png;base64,` like code below.

```
data:image/png;base64,R0lGODlhEAAQAMQAAORHHOVSKudfOulrSOp3WOyDZu6QdvCchPGolfO0o/XBs/fNwfjZ0frl3/zy7////wAAAAAAAA
```